# The practice of programming (Some confusing statements)

Tags: java, arrays, search

The other day I was reading *The practice of programming* by Kernighan and Rob Pike.

In the second chapter, under the *Searching* section, I read some of these lines which created confusion in my mind.

**"Nothing beats an array for storing static tabular data. Compile-time initialization 
makes it cheap and easy to construct such arrays. (In Java, the initialization occurs at 
run-time, but this is an unimportant implementation detail unless the arrays are large.)"**

My question is that how in any language its possible to have compile time initialization of array or variable if the user is going to supply it only at run time and also the memory allocation for variables takes place at run time. Without knowing the memory address how an array can be initialized?

Answer (score 1):

It does not say that the data is supplied at runtime. It just says "static" data. If it is known at compile-time and then the compiler could compile it right into the code. API keys, tables with "magic numbers", or error message texts fit into that pattern.

Comment: It is about array and arrays are supplied memory address at run time. How the initialization can take place if the memory is not known in advance?

Comment: If it is compiled into the binary, the array can be put into memory in the same way as a function: Just load bits from disk into memory en bloc. In C, an array is basically just a memory pointer, right? The data it points to could have been put there by a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood what the author was saying. Note:

This is a static array, in Java:

```
String[] suit = {
  "item 1", 
  "item 2", 
  "item 3", 
  "item 4"  
};
```

Now, Java doesn't allow you to declare *real* dynamic arrays like Delphi and another languages, for dynamic ones, we must choose another data structure called `ArrayList` like this example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If the user wants use the static array with runtime defined length, the most flexible way he can do is the following:

```
int maxsize = Integer.ParseInt(JOP.ShowInputDialog("give me a number")...);
int[] myArray = new int[maxsize]();
```

This is static array in Delphi:

```
const MyStaticArray : array [0..3] of Integer = (0, 1, 2, 3);
```

And this is dynamic array

```
var MyDinamicArray : array of Integer; 
    MaxSize: Integer;
begin
  MaxSize := StrToInt(InputBox(..,'Give me a number', ..));
  SetLength(MyDinamicArray, MaxSize); //Defines the array size, in runtime;
end;
```

> *My question is that how in any language its possible to have compile
>   time initialization of array or variable if the user is going to
>   supply it only at run time and also the memory allocation for
>   variables takes place at run time. Without knowing the memory address
>   how an array can be initialized?*

That said, we can easily see that, THIS is a "*compile time*" initialization (doesn't matter the fact of implementation details)

```
String[] suit = {
  "item 1", 
  "item 2", 
  "item 3", 
  "item 4"  
};
```

Once the array is initialized it **CANNOT BE** resized, so the OS can allocate the memory wherever it wants. And since arrays are *sequential* in the memory, by using indexes, Java knows what address you wants to get.

Considering the array above, this is the memory sketch:

//Program Memory

```
address   00A1
value   | 00BA |
alias     suit
```

//OS Memory

```
address      00BA      00BB       00BC       00BD      
value    | "item 1" | "item 2" | "item 3" | "item 4" | 
alias       suit[0]    suit[1]    suit[2]    suit[3]
```

The string is here to make it easy to understand, actually String is also a pointer to something.

Alias is how Java hides the pointer arithmetic, that is, allowing us to access indexes instead of memory addresses.

Here is some documentation about arrays:

Read [Static Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and see [Array List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: While it's a solid interpretation of what the authors might have meant, I think that the OP was **mislead** by the authors, rather than having misunderstood them - as they are talking about *definition* (the act of specifying something) rather than *initialization* (the act of allocating and creating the appropriate in-memory structures during the run of the program, representing what was defined).

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Well, I didn't read the book, what I posted is my interpretation of the paragraph, I cannot say anything else without a context. Then, my suggestion is that OP edit his question to add more completness about the subject

Comment: Sure, I was just pointing out that if the phrase "compile-time initialization" was used in the book, it's not really correct.

Comment: Thanks, nice observation!

Answer (score 0):

**From `JLS`**

#### 10.2. Array Variables

> A variable of array type holds a reference to an object. **Declaring a
> variable of array type does not create an array object or allocate any
> space for array components. It creates only the variable itself, which
> can contain a reference to an array.**
>
> However, the initializer part of a declarator (§8.3, §9.3, §14.4.1)
> may create an array, a reference to which then becomes the initial
> value of the variable.